# How to update the rows in a table in Material UI/React Table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm working on a table in Material UI/React that has multiple text fields (per row) and allows users to delete specific rows. Each row in the table is generated from a list, and I'm using React's state hooks to keep track of the list's state. My goal is to enable users to delete any row from the table. However, at the moment, when a user clicks the delete button, only the last row in the table is deleted. What modifications should I make to my code so that users can remove rows other than the last one in the table?

Page:

```
import { useCallback, useMemo, useState } from 'react';
import Head from 'next/head';
import { subDays, subHours } from 'date-fns';
import ArrowDownOnSquareIcon from '@heroicons/react/24/solid/ArrowDownOnSquareIcon';
import ArrowUpOnSquareIcon from '@heroicons/react/24/solid/ArrowUpOnSquareIcon';
import PlusIcon from '@heroicons/react/24/solid/PlusIcon';
import { Box, Button, Card, Container, Stack, SvgIcon, Typography } from '@mui/material';
import { useSelection } from 'src/hooks/use-selection';
import { Layout as DashboardLayout } from 'src/layouts/dashboard/layout';
import { TestSteps } from 'src/sections/createTests/testSteps';
import { TestsSearch } from 'src/sections/viewTests/tests-search';
import { applyPagination } from 'src/utils/apply-pagination';
import Grid from '@mui/material/Grid';
import AddCircleIcon from '@mui/icons-material/AddCircle';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';


const Page = () => {
  const [testSteps, setTestSteps] = useState([{id: uuidv4(), text:""}, {id: uuidv4(), text:""}]);

  function handleAddNewTestStep() {
    const newTestSteps = testSteps.concat({id: uuidv4(), text:""});
    setTestSteps(newTestSteps)
  }

  function handleRemove(id) {
    console.log(id)
    const newList = testSteps.filter((item) => item.id !== id);
    console.log(newList)
    setTestSteps(newList);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>
          Customers | Devias Kit
        </title>
      </Head>
      <Box
        component="main"
        sx={{
          flexGrow: 1,
          py: 8
        }}
      >
        <Container maxWidth="xl">
          <Stack spacing={3}>
            <Stack
              direction="row"
              justifyContent="space-between"
              spacing={4}
            >
              <Stack spacing={1}>
                <Typography variant="h4">
                  Tests Steps
                </Typography>
              </Stack>
            </Stack>
            <Card sx={{ p: 2 }}>
                <Typography sx={{ mb: 2 }}>
                  Scenario 1 - User enters a valid name and email address and submits the form successfully.
                </Typography>
              <TestSteps
                count={testSteps.length}
                items={testSteps}
                handleRemove={handleRemove}
              />
              <Grid xs={12}>
                  <Grid xs={12}>
                    <Button variant="text" onClick={handleAddNewTestStep}>
                    <Typography>
                      Add New Test Step
                    </Typography>
                    <AddCircleIcon sx={{ ml: 1 }}/>
                    </Button>
                  </Grid>
              </Grid>
            </Card>
          </Stack>
          <div align="center">
            <Button variant="contained" size="small" align="center" sx={{mt: 2}}
               href="/viewTest"
            >
              Add Test Steps
            </Button>
          </div>
        </Container>
      </Box>
    </>
  );
};

Page.getLayout = (page) => (
  <DashboardLayout>
    {page}
  </DashboardLayout>
);

export default Page;
```

MUI Table:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { format } from 'date-fns';
import {
  Avatar,
  Box,
  Card,
  Checkbox,
  Stack,
  Table,
  TableBody,
  TableCell,
  TableHead,
  TablePagination,
  TableRow,
  Typography,
} from '@mui/material';
import { Scrollbar } from 'src/components/scrollbar';
import { getInitials } from 'src/utils/get-initials';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import Grid from '@mui/material/Grid';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import AddCircleIcon from '@mui/icons-material/AddCircle';
import MenuItem from '@mui/material/MenuItem';
import CloseIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Close';

export const TestSteps = (props) => {

  const {
    count = 0,
    handleRemove,
    items = [],
    onDeselectAll,
    onDeselectOne,
    onPageChange = () => {},
    onRowsPerPageChange,
    onSelectAll,
    onSelectOne,
    page = 0,
    rowsPerPage = 0,
    selected = []
  } = props;

  return (
    <Grid xs={12}>
      <Grid xs={12}>
        <Scrollbar>
          <Box sx={{ minWidth: 800 }}>
            <Table>
              <TableHead>
                <TableRow>
                  <TableCell padding="checkbox">
                    Step
                  </TableCell>
                  <TableCell>
                    Test Step
                  </TableCell>
                  <TableCell sx={{mr: 2}}>
                    Page
                  </TableCell>
                  <TableCell padding="checkbox" />
                </TableRow>
              </TableHead>
              <TableBody>
              {items.map((customer, i) => {
                return (
                    <TableRow
                    >
                      <TableCell padding="checkbox">
                        {i + 1}
                      </TableCell>
                      <TableCell>
                        <TextField
                          required
                          id="outlined-required"
                          label="Test Step"
                          placeholder="Enter Test Step"
                          multiline
                          fullWidth
                        />
                      </TableCell>
                      <TableCell sx={{mr: 2}}>
                      <TextField
                        required
                        select
                        id="outlined-required"
                        label="Choose Page"
                        placeholder="Choose Page"
                        fullWidth
                      >
                        <MenuItem key="testpage1" value="testpage1">
                              testpage1.com
                        </MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem key="testpage2" value="testpage2">
                              testpage2.com
                        </MenuItem>
                      </TextField>
                      </TableCell>
                      <TableCell padding="checkbox">

                         <Button id={customer.id} onClick={event => handleRemove(event.currentTarget.id)}>
                          <CloseIcon />
                         </Button>

                      </TableCell>
                    </TableRow>
                  )
                })}
              </TableBody>
            </Table>
          </Box>
        </Scrollbar>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
  );
};
```

GIF:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

you don't need the event object to handle this, you are already mapping through `items` to display table rows so you can simply give the item id of the current itteration to your `handleRemove` function instead:

```js
<Button
  onClick={() => {
     handleRemove(customer.id);
  }}
>
 <CloseIcon />
</Button>
```

also add an unique key to each element inside the returned array of function:

```js
{items.map((customer, i) => {
  return (
    <TableRow key={i}> 
   /...
    </TableRow>
  )
})
```

better would be `key={customer.id}` if ids are always deffirents and defined

Comment: Thanks for the response! I still have the same issue after making this change. It'll only remove the last item in my table.

Comment: @user3697597 and it is always the id of the last item which is given as parameter to the function?

Comment: each button has a different, id. when I pull the HTML for it each button's id is different.

Comment: Yes I mean when `handleRemove` is called you lof the id, is it always the id of the last item which is passed to the function or whatever the id is always the last item is deleted

Comment: Any tips on how I could make it not the last item?

Comment: tel me first if the function handleRemove get always the id of the last item or if the last item is removed regardless of which id is given

Comment: the function removes the correct id. however the text fields in the table do not reflect that.

Comment: @user3697597 you may need an unique key I updated my answer

Comment: Thanks, it worked!! I used a UUID for a key instead. Why did adding a special key to the row allow me to remove it?

Comment: The only issue is now all of the text in other text fields in other rows are deleted. i am solving that now.

Comment: take a look [here](https://www.datainfinities.com/18/each-child-in-a-list-should-have-a-unique-key-prop#:~:text=The%20Warning%3A%20Each%20child%20in,be%20unique%20across%20all%20siblings.) in **Why each element in a list should have a unique key?** section

Comment: Both `Page` and `TestStep` are rerendered so  inputs values are not tracked. to resolve this you need to control inputs with `onChange` event listener and `value={example}` so each time you handle changes you update `example` and `example` is a state, usually this is what we do in React. An obvious solution is to update directly `testSteps` with onChange then retrive the `value` from there but this will make `Page` then `TestStep` rerender on each key press, INSANE. you want at least only `TestStep`  to be rerendered unless you want to update `testStep` directly from `TestStep` inputs changes

Comment: Still facing the same issue. The code only works as expected when I set a default value and do not edit that default value.

Comment: To understand better, just create a state `const [test,setTest] = useState ('')` then inTextField you put `value={test}` and `onChange={(e)=>{setTest(e.target.value)}}` you will see them update all together because they share the salue `value` so u understand! you need a `state` for each Textfield or only one state that holds all the values for each textField an array for example when each item is bind to a specific Textfield. but this is a different issue this has nothing to do with this question. because this are consequences of updating the state, you may open another one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254210/discussion-between-user3697597-and-ahmed-sbai).

Comment: @user3697597 did u see what I sugesst in chat?